# ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Tags: oracle

A couple mornings now my Oracle database has hit this error and not come up for an hour or so.  Then it works fine for the rest of the day without needing any interaction.  But this messes up my apps relying on Oracle being up for the whole time they run.

Any ideas?

```
2009-09-11 04:52:56,343 [Orion Launcher] ERROR conn.ConnectionService verifyRepositoryEx.496 - Invalid Connection Pool. ERROR = ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

2009-09-11 04:52:56,734 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.sysman.ias.ias.IASIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:56,890 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.sysman.eml.target.slb.common.SLBIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:56,953 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.sysman.eml.ssl.intg.SSLIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:57,015 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.tip.oem.central.domain.ProcessConnectDomainIntg
2009-09-11 04:52:57,015 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.tip.oem.central.instance.ProcessConnectInstanceIntg
2009-09-11 04:52:57,015 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.webdb.admin.em.PortalIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:57,015 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.webdb.admin.em.SSOIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:57,015 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.reports.em.RepIntg
2009-09-11 04:52:57,015 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.sysman.ocs.mntr.target.OcsEmailIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:57,031 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.sysman.ocs.mntr.target.OcsOidIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:57,031 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.sysman.ocs.mntr.target.OcsOvfIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:57,031 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.sysman.ocs.mntr.target.OcsWebconfIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:57,031 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.sysman.ocs.mntr.target.OcsWirelessIntg
2009-09-11 04:52:57,031 [Orion Launcher] ERROR app.ContextInitializer contextInitialized.272 - Integration Class not found: oracle.sysman.ocs.mntr.target.OcsCalGrpIntegration
2009-09-11 04:52:57,078 [OmsServiceDriver thread] WARN  jdbc.ConnectionCache _getConnection.303 - Got a fatal exeption when getting a connection; Error code = 1034; Cleaning up cache and retrying
2009-09-11 04:52:57,078 [OmsServiceDriver thread] WARN  jdbc.ConnectionCache _getConnection.306 - ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
```

Comment: Does this only happen during certain times of the day? Is it every day? Do you run queries over night that encounter problems? Is it possible you have a long running backup process or other application that might be tying up connections?

Comment: Do you close the database at night to back it up ?

Comment: What platform is this Oracle Database running on?

Answer (score 1):

This generally occurs when you are trying to connect to a database that is not running.
You can generally visualise Oracle as a collection of worker bees all gathered round a honeycomb. The 'Shared Memory Realm' is the honeycomb; if its not there you've got big problems.

**What is contained in the alert log?**

I'd start by figuring out what schedule jobs are running at the OS level on the server.
Something is either shutting the database down and then restarting it (backup?) or you may have some kind of 'watchdog' task that is restarting the instance after it crashes for some reason.